# upload image from gallery or camera to rest api (error: status: false, message: User Does Not Exists!, data: null)

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want upload image from gallery to api here is my image api

```
Future  profileImageUser(String user_id, String image) async {

      String url = 'api';
      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
          body: {
            'user_id': user_id,
            'image': image
          }
      );
      var convertedDataJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return convertedDataJson;
    }
```

Here is how i am getting user id and image to upload it through rest api

```
 ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
  Future _imgFromCamera() async {
    final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);


    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      final bytes = File(_image!.path).readAsBytesSync();
      String img64 = base64Encode(bytes);
     print(img64);
    });
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      var myProfile = _image;
      print(myProfile);
      var myId = prefs.getString('user_id');
      print(myId);
      var rsp = await profileImageUser(
        myProfile.toString(),
        myId.toString(),
      );
      print(rsp);
       if (rsp['status'] == true) {
        print(rsp);
      } else {
        print('failed');
      }
    }
  }
```

when i upload image from gallery or camera it print id and image as follow

```
I/flutter ( 6665): Instance of 'XFile'
I/flutter ( 6665): 111
```

but it also show error that user doest not exist

```
I/flutter ( 6665): {status: false, message: User Does Not Exists!, data: null}
```

kindly provide a solution.

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Future  profileImageUser(String image,String user_id) async {

  String url = 'http://bitborgtech.com/appss/api/update_profile_image';
  final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
      body: {
        'user_id': user_id,
        'image': image
      }
  );
  var convertedDataJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
  return convertedDataJson;
}
```

Comment: no its not i check its available

Comment: @RashidAli, Why you send `myProfile.toString(),`, you need to send  `myId `.

Comment: i am assining image to myprofile variable that i am getting from gallery and than sending it as api need both image and id

Comment: bro, just check my api call, and try this, hope that will be solved

Comment: sorry but whta solution should i try

Comment: you just send a wrong parameter in api. image to id, id to image.

Comment: brother i checked it kindly tell me exactly where

Comment: Future  profileImageUser(String image,String user_id)

Comment: I am doing exactly like that kindly check it api brother

Comment: you send  var rsp = await profileImageUser(
        myProfile.toString(),
        myId.toString(),
      ); and receive Future profileImageUser(String user_id,String image)

Comment: Thank you so much you were ryt bur now i am getting this error

Comment: status: 400, message: There is some trouble to proceed your action!, data: null

Comment: yes, image not receiving properly.

Comment: i have to try another way to send image than

Comment: ok, please up vote the answer.